# Jquery script is not working on content pages

Tags: jquery

I've a "SearchText" Textbox in master page. I used the script code for search suggestion
my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#<%=SearchText.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "SearchSuggestions.asmx/GetSuggestions",
                        data: "{ 'searchValue': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (result) {
                            response(result.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

it works fine on Default.aspx. but on other content pages this code does not seems working.

Comment: use jQuery no conflict and then try

Comment: Look in the browser's JavaScript console. Are there any errors there?

Comment: please paste the console error log also

Comment: every thing is fine on master page. it does not gives search  suggestions on content pages

Comment: there is no error in javaScript console

Comment: this could be a useful link at asp.net forum: http://forums.asp.net/t/1961808.aspx?Jquery+is+not+working+with+master+page

Comment: Are your other pages in the same folder as Default.aspx? And do they definitely use the same master page?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute url value.

Your ajax request currently asks

```
http://yoursite.com/{content-page-address}/SearchSuggestions.asmx/GetSuggestions
```

you want

```
http://yoursite.com/SearchSuggestions.asmx/GetSuggestions
```